# Range of elements into a vector?

Tags: python, numpy

I have to check if a specific segment of a vector, let's say the elements from the 8000th to the last one are larger than some real number. Since I am a noob in Python I tried the following:

```
if (vec[8000:Nout-1] > 2.):
    print('test ok!')
```

I declared the vec as `vec = np.zeros(Nout)` where `Nout==10000`. Thus I filled the vector and after the calculation I have my numbers inside of it.

The error I receive is:

> `The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

I do not know if or how use `a.any`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use it like that:

```
Nout = 10000
vec = np.zeros(Nout)

if (vec[8000:Nout-1].all() > 2):
    print('test ok!')
```

This will check that all elements from index `8000` to `Nout-1` in `vec` are greater than 2.

Answer (score 1):

To understand the issue, try looking at the output of `(vec[8000:Nout-1] > 2.)`. Let me make a simplified version of your example

`vec = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
print vec > 2
[False, False, True, True]`

So it is giving an array with the result applied to each element of the list. So when you call if on this, you get the given error message that the truth value of an array is ambiguous.

As it suggests, this can be fixed by using

`import numpy as np
if np.all(vec > 2):
    print('test ok')`

or

`import numpy as np
if (vec > 2).all():
    print('test ok')`

I personally prefer the first implementation as it makes it clear this is a numpy function, but each to their own.

#### Additional

The rational for this behavior in numpy is that one perform operations on parts of an array, i.e.

`vec = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
vec[vec > 2] = 0
print vec
[1, 2, 0, 0]`